# Вертикальное выравнивание картинки в div?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть такой сайт http://marinatravel.kz/
В самом низу реализована автоматическая карусель. (Наши партнеры). Так вот изображения которые по высоте меньше выравнивается поверху, а нужно что бы по центру. Ниже принтсрикн.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Как правильно поддкоректировать css что бы изображения выравнивались по центру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

строка 28 owl.carousel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    /* float: left; */     /* <---------- remove */
    display: inline-block; /* <---------- add */
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Например картинки выровнять через `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: Поставил, не работает(((

Comment: @duddeniska вертикальное ориентирование используется только с элементами `inline` или `inline-block` – http://htmlbook.ru/css/vertical-align

Comment: ну у меня в верстке этого нету,

Comment: @duddeniska я предлагаю вариант, не буду же я изучать вашу верстку и делать за вас работу. Посмотрите еще в сторону выравнивание через js